# How to merge arrays of hashes with matching a column value

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, merge

I want to merge two arrays `array1` and `array2` with matching a column values. Plot ID may or may not match between two arrays. Matching column is Plot ID in array1 and Plotting ID in array2.

Dominant is array1. Column values in array1 should come at first in the expected output.

Merge array2 column names with zero values if array2 doesn't match with array1

```
array1 = [
{"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plot ID" => 234},
{"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plot ID" => 235},
{"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plot ID" => 236},
{"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plot ID" => 237},
{"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plot ID" => 238},
{"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plot ID" => 239},
{"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plot ID" => 240},
{"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plot ID" => 241}
]

array2 = [
{"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plotting ID" => 234, "size"=> 20, "visit" => 10, "price" => 103},
{"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plotting ID" => 500,  "size"=> 40, "visit" => 22, "price" => 233},
{"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plotting ID" => 236,  "size"=> 25, "visit" => 34, "price" => 423},
{"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plotting ID" => 600,  "size"=> 79, "visit" => 55, "price" => 234}
]
```

Expected output:

```
[
{"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plot ID" => 234, "size"=> 20, "visit" => 10, "price" => 103},
{"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plot ID" => 235, "size"=> 0, "visit" => 0, "price" => 0},
{"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plot ID" => 236, "size"=> 25, "visit" => 34, "price" => 423},
{"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plot ID" => 237, "size"=> 0, "visit" => 0, "price" => 0},
{"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plot ID" => 238, "size"=> 0, "visit" => 0, "price" => 0},
{"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plot ID" => 239, "size"=> 0, "visit" => 0, "price" => 0},
{"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plot ID" => 240, "size"=> 0, "visit" => 0, "price" => 0},
{"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plot ID" => 241, "size"=> 0, "visit" => 0, "price" => 0}
]
```

Comment: `[{"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plot ID" => 234}, "size"=> 20, visit => 10, "price" => 103}]` you sure you want the result in this way?

Comment: @GaganGupta Yes. I need result in this way.

Comment: there is a syntax error in the expected output, you have an extra `}` in the middle

Comment: there's syntax error in the way you want.

Comment: @GaganGupta Updated the expected output

Comment: Do both 'Plot ID' and 'Date' need to match to merge them together?

Comment: Only Plot ID to match and merge

Comment: And what array is the dominant one? In the case the dates don't match, do you want to keep the `"Date"` value of the hash in `array1` or `array2`?

Comment: array1 is dominant one. Matching column differs as Plot ID in array1 and Plotting ID in array2.

Comment: Keep Date value of array1

Comment: @GaganGupta Let me know any inputs needed from me

Comment: You've answered a few questions in comments. Please edit your question to incorporate that information, for the benefit of readers, now and in future, who do not read all comments. That will also head off additional downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer only works if `array2` doesn't contain any duplicate `Plotting ID` values. (If there are duplicate `Plotting ID` it still works, but it uses the last record of the once precent in the array.)

```
array1 = [{"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plot ID" => 234}, {"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plot ID" => 235}, {"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plot ID" => 236}, {"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plot ID" => 237}, {"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plot ID" => 238}, {"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plot ID" => 239}, {"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plot ID" => 240}, {"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plot ID" => 241}]
array2 = [{"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plotting ID" => 234, "size"=> 20, "visit" => 10, "price" => 103}, {"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plotting ID" => 500,  "size"=> 40, "visit" => 22, "price" => 233}, {"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plotting ID" => 236,  "size"=> 25, "visit" => 34, "price" => 423}, {"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plotting ID" => 600,  "size"=> 79, "visit" => 55, "price" => 234}]

array2_lookup = array2.map(&:dup).map { |record| [record.delete('Plotting ID'), record] }.to_h
array2_lookup.default = { 'size' => 0, 'visit' => 0, 'price' => 0 }
pp array1.map { |record| array2_lookup[record['Plot ID']].merge(record) }
# [{"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "size"=>20, "visit"=>10, "price"=>103, "Plot ID"=>234},
#  {"size"=>0, "visit"=>0, "price"=>0, "Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Plot ID"=>235},
#  {"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "size"=>25, "visit"=>34, "price"=>423, "Plot ID"=>236},
#  {"size"=>0, "visit"=>0, "price"=>0, "Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Plot ID"=>237},
#  {"size"=>0, "visit"=>0, "price"=>0, "Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Plot ID"=>238},
#  {"size"=>0, "visit"=>0, "price"=>0, "Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Plot ID"=>239},
#  {"size"=>0, "visit"=>0, "price"=>0, "Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Plot ID"=>240},
#  {"size"=>0, "visit"=>0, "price"=>0, "Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Plot ID"=>241}]
```

The above solution first loops over `array2` and converts it to a hash, by deleting the key/value pair `'Plotting ID'` from the hash and using the value as key. For this reason I've added the `.map(&:dup)` call, preventing the original hashes in `array2` from mutating. If the hash mutation is not an issue for you you can simply remove this.

After creating the lookup hash I've added a default that is used when merging the hashes. All that is left to do now is loop through `array1`, lookup the record (if any) or use the default and merge that with the current element.

This answer leaves the keys somewhat scrambled, but since a hash is based on key lookup anyway (not key/value order) this shouldn't be a huge issue. If you'd like to have all keys in the same order you can do so by providing all the keys to the default, setting their values to `nil` (or any other value since they are overwritten):

```
array2_lookup.default = { 'Date' => nil, 'size' => 0, 'visit' => 0, 'price' => 0 }
# ...                        ^ added placeholder for ordering purposes
# [{"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "size"=>20, "visit"=>10, "price"=>103, "Plot ID"=>234},
#  {"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "size"=>0, "visit"=>0, "price"=>0, "Plot ID"=>235},
#  {"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "size"=>25, "visit"=>34, "price"=>423, "Plot ID"=>236},
#  {"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "size"=>0, "visit"=>0, "price"=>0, "Plot ID"=>237},
#  {"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "size"=>0, "visit"=>0, "price"=>0, "Plot ID"=>238},
#  {"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "size"=>0, "visit"=>0, "price"=>0, "Plot ID"=>239},
#  {"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "size"=>0, "visit"=>0, "price"=>0, "Plot ID"=>240},
#  {"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "size"=>0, "visit"=>0, "price"=>0, "Plot ID"=>241}]
```

Comment: Can we merge array2 at the end instead of front

Comment: You can swap the order of the resulting hash by using `record` as the receiver and passing `array2_lookup[record['Plot ID']]` as `merge` argument. However this does swap the dominance. To combat this we'll have to add a block that tells merge to use the old value on conflict, rather than the new value. `record.merge(array2_lookup[record['Plot ID']]) { |_key, old, _new| old }` See: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge

Comment: What should I to update if I need to match Date column too

Comment: You can do the same thing, but use an array with the `Plotting ID` and `Date` as hash key. Then look the value up using this combination. https://gist.github.com/3limin4t0r/47c26c8d2786b954c2b6fbd779eb15ee

Comment: Your answer works well for me. What should I do if I don't need default values for array2?

Comment: @Galet Do you mean that you want the default values to be `nil` or that the attribute (*size*, *visit* and *price*) should not be added?

Comment: Here is the expected result => [{"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plot ID" => 234, "size"=> 20, "visit" => 10, "price" => 103},{"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plot ID" => 236, "size"=> 25, "visit" => 34, "price" => 423}]

Comment: Is it possible to produce the above output?

Comment: @Galet In that case you should remove the `array2_lookup` *default* assignment and change the line below to `array1.map { |record| [record, array2_lookup[record['Plot ID']]].compact }.select { |records| records.size == 2 }.map { |record1, record2| record2.merge(record1) }`.

Answer (score 1):

```rb
array1 = [{"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plot ID" => 234}, {"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plot ID" => 235}, {"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plot ID" => 236}, {"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plot ID" => 237}, {"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plot ID" => 238}, {"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plot ID" => 239}, {"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plot ID" => 240}, {"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plot ID" => 241}]
array2 = [{"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plotting ID" => 234, "size"=> 20, "visit" => 10, "price" => 103}, {"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plotting ID" => 500,  "size"=> 40, "visit" => 22, "price" => 233}, {"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plotting ID" => 236,  "size"=> 25, "visit" => 34, "price" => 423}, {"Date" => "2019-01-01", "Plotting ID" => 600,  "size"=> 79, "visit" => 55, "price" => 234}]

grouped = (array2 + array1).group_by { |h| h["Plot ID"] || h["Plotting ID"] }
merged = grouped.values.map { |a| a.inject(:merge) }

# and in case you want exact formatting:
template = { "Date" => nil, "Plot ID" => nil, "size"=> 0, "visit" => 0, "price" => 0 }
normalized = merged.each { |h| template.merge(h).slice(*template.keys) }
```

You can see how each line of code does one meaningful and independent transformation of the data. I find code like this much easier to step through in a debugger.

Learn to compose those built-in `Enumerable` and `Hash` methods and greatly simplify your code!

Comment: Name of Plot ID differs in array1 and array2. Plot ID in array1 and Plotting ID in array2

Comment: Oh, that was intentional? Fixed.

Comment: I want to merge column names from array2 with values as zero even if there is no match. I don't see column names from array2 in result if none of them matched.

Answer (score 1):

If i get correctly the answer, maybe this is a possible option.

```
template = {"size"=> 0, "visit" => 0, "price" => 0}
array1.map do |h|
  begin
    h.merge!(template, array2.find { |hh| hh["Plotting ID"] == h["Plot ID"] })
     .then { |hh| hh.delete("Plotting ID") }
  rescue TypeError
  end
end
```

I used `rescue` because find could return `nil`.

---

Option without `rescue`:

```
template = {"size"=> 0, "visit" => 0, "price" => 0}
array1.map do |h|
  h2 = {} || array2.find { |hh| hh["Plotting ID"] == h["Plot ID"] if hh.has_key("Plotting ID") } 
  h.merge!(template, h2).then { |hh| hh.delete("Plotting ID") }
end
```

Even one liner:

```
array1.map { |h| h.merge!({"size"=> 0, "visit" => 0, "price" => 0}, {} || array2.find { |hh| hh["Plotting ID"] == h["Plot ID"] if hh.has_key("Plotting ID") }).then { |hh| hh.delete("Plotting ID") } }
```

---

It modifies array1, so:

```
array1

# [{"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Plot ID"=>234, "size"=>20, "visit"=>10, "price"=>103}, {"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Plot ID"=>235, "size"=>0, "visit"=>0, "price"=>0}, {"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Plot ID"=>236, "size"=>25, "visit"=>34, "price"=>423}, {"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Plot ID"=>237, "size"=>0, "visit"=>0, "price"=>0}, {"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Plot ID"=>238, "size"=>0, "visit"=>0, "price"=>0}, {"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Plot ID"=>239, "size"=>0, "visit"=>0, "price"=>0}, {"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Plot ID"=>240, "size"=>0, "visit"=>0, "price"=>0}, {"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Plot ID"=>241, "size"=>0, "visit"=>0, "price"=>0}]
```

Comment: Is there any other solution without rescue option

Comment: @karan, yes, added the option (also a one liner)

Answer (score 1):

```
template = (array2.first.keys - array1.first.keys - ["Plotting ID"]).product([0]).to_h
  #=> {"size"=>0, "visit"=>0, "price"=>0}

h = array1.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h[g["Plot ID"]] = g.merge(template) } 
  #=> {234=>{"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Plot ID"=>234, "size"=>0, "visit"=>0, "price"=>0},
  #    235=>{"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Plot ID"=>235, "size"=>0, "visit"=>0, "price"=>0}, 
  #    ...
  #    241=>{"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Plot ID"=>241, "size"=>0, "visit"=>0, "price"=>0}}

array2.each_with_object(h) { |g,f| f.update(g["Plotting ID"]=>
    g.transform_keys { |k| k == "Plotting ID" ? "Plot ID" : k }) }.values
  #=> [{"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Plot ID"=>234, "size"=>20, "visit"=>10, "price"=>103}, 
  #    {"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Plot ID"=>235, "size"=> 0, "visit"=> 0, "price"=>  0},
  #    {"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Plot ID"=>236, "size"=>25, "visit"=>34, "price"=>423},
  #    {"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Plot ID"=>237, "size"=> 0, "visit"=> 0, "price"=>  0},
  #    {"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Plot ID"=>238, "size"=> 0, "visit"=> 0, "price"=>  0},
  #    {"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Plot ID"=>239, "size"=> 0, "visit"=> 0, "price"=>  0},
  #    {"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Plot ID"=>240, "size"=> 0, "visit"=> 0, "price"=>  0},
  #    {"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Plot ID"=>241, "size"=> 0, "visit"=> 0, "price"=>  0},
  #    {"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Plot ID"=>500, "size"=>40, "visit"=>22, "price"=>233},
  #    {"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Plot ID"=>600, "size"=>79, "visit"=>55, "price"=>234}]
```

If desired, `h` could be substituted out in the last expression.

It would be simpler to define `template` as follows:

```
template = (%w| size visit price |).product([0]).to_h
```

This has the disadvantage, however, of being fragile to changes to the names and/or numbers of keys in the elements of `array2`.

Though less efficient, the following may be clearer and easier to maintain.

```
a2 = array2.map { |h| h.transform_keys { |k| k == "Plotting ID" ? "Plot ID" : k } }
  # => [{"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Plot ID"=>234, "size"=>20, "visit"=>10, "price"=>103},
  #     {"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Plot ID"=>500, "size"=>40, "visit"=>22, "price"=>233},
  #     {"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Plot ID"=>236, "size"=>25, "visit"=>34, "price"=>423},
  #     {"Date"=>"2019-01-01", "Plot ID"=>600, "size"=>79, "visit"=>55, "price"=>234}] 
template = (a2.first.keys - array1.first.keys).product([0]).to_h
  #=> <same as earlier value>
h = array1.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h[g["Plot ID"]] = g.merge(template) }
  #=> <same as earlier value>
a2.each_with_object(h) { |g,f| f.update(g["Plot ID"]=>g) }.values
  #=> <same as earlier value>
```